# convert ios code to java using jcocoa

Tags: java, android, ios, objective-c

I have got a work to convert an ios application to android for this i have full ios app source code,but i dont have any knowledge of ios development.
So,to convert it into android i have found a method i.e.
jcocoa from http://code.google.com/p/objc2j/downloads/detail?name=converter.properties&can=2&q= 
but i dont know how to use it i have complete code of ios app in zip format.
Can anyone please provide me with the explainition on how to use it via command prompt.
And one more thing how can i run ios apps on windows platform,i have tried ipadian but its not working.Any help will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

It says that android is not yet supported  (and Android JVM in future). Maybe you'll have more success with apportable.

Comment: Thanks but in brief can u tel me how to run it via command line.

Comment: java -jar objc2j.jar "path to your sources" as mentioned in the wiki https://code.google.com/p/objc2j/wiki/Usage